# Git: how to get all the files changed and new files in a folder or zip?

Tags: git

As my question says, after changing files and adding new files in my repository, I normally commit files with **git**, but sometimes I need all the modified / changed files copied to a folder for organizing-myself reasons.

Any option?

Comment: If you tell us what you're actually trying to accomplish, our answers might be a little bit more helpful.

Comment: It depends, sometimes just to ftp them

Comment: But "to ftp them" is not a goal by itself.  What is the rationale of doing this?  I never wanted to create a zip of just the changed files, so I'm wondering about the use case.

Comment: In this case it's more about copying them to a folder, and not zipping

Comment: Ah, the old "why would you ever want to do something that I never do?". Use case is completely irrelevant to the question. The question is succinct enough.

Comment: @Cascabel: perhaps OP wants a backup of the files in case git or their git GUI fucks up and wipes them out, and is reluctant to deal with [git's crappy experience](https://ohshitgit.com/) trying to restore them.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Assuming you mean you haven't yet committed, and want to package up all of the files that currently have local *modifications* (but **not** completely new files), you can get the list of modified files with `git ls-files --modified`. If you want the files which were changed by the last commit, you could use `git diff --name-only HEAD^`. Where you go from there is up to you. Examples:

```
zip modified-files.zip $(git ls-files --modified)
cp --parents $(git ls-files --modified) ../modified-files # Linux
rsync -R $(git ls-files --modified) ../modified-files # macOS
```

Note that this is using the versions of files in the working tree currently.

If you have spaces in filenames, you'll have to go to a little more trouble.

(Of course, depending on what you're really trying to do, you might be looking for [`git stash`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash), which stashes away all modified files and leaves you with a clean working tree, or you could simply want to make a temporary branch to commit to.)

Comment: this is without commiting, how can I get the new files too.

Comment: When I say new files that means before adding them to the repository

Comment: I think I found what I was looking for: cp $(git ls-files --modified --others) modified-files. Thx a lot.

Comment: Is there anyway to exclude certain extensions or filenames or even subfolders?

Comment: Pls, look at my new question I am sure this is a child's game for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126732/git-how-to-exclude-a-subfolder-in-a-repository

Comment: use --parents to copy and create the folders: cp --parents $(git ls-files --modified) ../copyfolder/

Comment: you can use $(git diff --name-only HASH1 HASH2) to get files between 2 commits :)

Comment: I have .zip file at repo I have modify only 1 file under that now what should i do to push my changes do i need to push whole .zip or i can push only 1 file under that any suggestion please ..?

Comment: How to include new files there?

Comment: For Windows users, you can do it too using WSL

Comment: @RussellEngland any way to exclude .gitignore files?

Comment: `zip modified-files.zip $(git ls-files --modified)` only works with modified files. staged files WILL NOT be included.

Comment: For macOS: `rsync -R $(git ls-files --modified) ../modified-files`, because [`--parents` is not an option for `cp` on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246070/cp-parents-option-on-mac) @RussellEngland.

Answer (score 81):

To do exactly what you requested (assuming you already committed and want to create an archive of the files changed by the last commit), you could do:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD `git diff HEAD^ HEAD --name-only` > a.zip
```

If you have removed files in a commit, to prevent a pathspec error use `--diff-filter=d`:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD `git diff --diff-filter=d HEAD^ HEAD --name-only` > a.zip
```

But maybe you actually want to create a patch using:

```
git diff HEAD^ HEAD > a.patch
```

and apply this patch where you need it using:

```
patch -p1 < a.patch
```

Of course, applying a patch only works if your target directory already contains the old version of your repository.

Comment: i recommend using `git format-patch` instead of piping `git diff` to a file

Comment: this is after commiting, how can I get the new files too.

Comment: By new files you mean untracked files in your working directory?  Well, just tell us what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry for my imprecision, I upvote you, I save your answer because it is also very interesting if I want the last commited files

Comment: Pls, look at my new question I am sure this is a child's game for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126732/git-how-to-exclude-a-subfolder-in-a-repository

Comment: One problem is, when you deleted something, you will get error: "fatal: path not found: XYZ"

Comment: git archive worked perfect for me.  I had to get the last 2 commits, so I did one of these:
`git archive --format=zip HEAD \`git diff HEAD~2 HEAD --name-only\` > a.zip`

Comment: The first command in this answer didn't work for me on Windows (7).  For some reason it complained that the --name-only option was unknown.  I think it's probably just an escaping issue?  So to be lazy I installed Cygwin and was able to run it correctly from the Cygwin prompt.

Comment: @JohnBubriski:  No, it's not just an escaping issue.  The syntax used in the first command is POSIX shell syntax.  Unfortunately, Windows doesn't come with a POSIX shell (or any usable shell, for that matter), so installing Cygwin is a good idea in any case.

Comment: What if I want to do the same as in this solution but including, for example, last two revisions?

Comment: I've also found that if one of the commits was for a file removal, the archive breaks with a 'pathspec [file-path] did not match' - error.

Comment: Okay, solved the pathspec error. If you have deleted files in your commits, use --diff-filter=d

Comment: You should also probably use the `--relative` flag on the `git diff` subcommand, since `git archive` archives files relative to the current working directory. That allows the command to work inside subdirectories of your tree (archiving the diff for that subdirectory).

Comment: I have .zip file at repo I have modify only 1 file under that now what should i do to push my changes do i need to push whole .zip or i can push only 1 file under that any suggestion please ..?

Answer (score 21):

If you use TortoiseGIt, it provides this too.
Choose the folder, in explorer
Right click,Choose menu, TortoiseGit-> Show Log.

Select working directory and the last commiitted version.
Right click. Compare revisions. Select files you want to save/export.
Right Click. Export to folder. Done.

Comment: I wish the TortoiseGit export tool allowed you to select multiple commits.

Comment: It's astounding how much functionality Tortoise packs into the UI.

Answer (score 9):

Zip the modified and newly created files in the git repository

```
zip mychanges.zip $({ (git ls-files --others --exclude-standard) ; (git ls-files --modified)})
```

Comment: This doesn't include new files (marked as "new file:" by `git status`).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have deleted or renamed files, this should do the trick

**Copy:**

```
cp --parents $(git status -s | egrep "M|A|AM" | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev) destination_folder
```

**Zip:**

```
zip modified.zip $(git status -s | egrep "M|A|AM" | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev)
```

Comment: the cp --parents seem to copy/create directories along with file, is there way to copy on the files and not create directory. I guess removing the --parents argument works just fine :) .

Comment: --parents
              use full source file name under DIRECTORY

The --parents argument places the files into the same folders structure on destination that they were on origin.
For example, if you have modified files on include and source folders, the --parents argument places them into include and source on destination. 
[orig/folder_a/file_1, orig/folder_b/file_2] -> [dest/folder_a/file_1, dest/folder_b/file_2]

This is very useful if you have modified files on different folders on the same project (for example include and source folders)

Comment: If you add '??' to egrep "M|A|AM" like egrep "M|A|AM|??", you will also copy files that are not under version-control. This is useful for new files that are not added or commited yet

Comment: When I add "M|A|AM|??" I get: `egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid`. 

Comment: I'm using GNU grep 3.3 (2018-05-11)

Comment: why do you need rev?  I just used -f3 instead of -f1 and it appears to get the correct column

Comment: @gonzobrains: `-f3` won't work for `AM` files (it will return an empty string). Anyway, the `egrep "M|A|AM"` will falsely match files that contain `M` or `A` in their name. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76386165/1269037) for a correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `git ls-files --modified` command listed in other answers doesn't include new files.

I've been using the command below to back *[new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000163/git-list-new-files-only) and* modified files in case my IDE screwed up when syncing from remote branches and its "Smart checkout" feature wasn't that smart:

```bash
cp --parents $(git status -s | egrep "^A|^ M" | cut -c 4-) ../modified-files # Linux
rsync -R $(git status -s | egrep "^A|^ M" | cut -c 4-) ../modified-files # macOS
```

Let's look at how we obtain the list of new and modified files:

```bash
git status -s | grep "^A\|^ M" | cut -c 4-
```

- `-s` stands for `--short` and it will produce an output like this:

  ```
   M .gitignore
  A  _includes/code/howto/manage-data.create.py
  A  _includes/code/howto/manage-data.create.ts
   M _includes/code/howto/search.generative.ts
   M _includes/code/howto/search.hybrid.ts
  AM developers/weaviate/manage-data/create.mdx
  ?? _includes/code/howto/jeopardy_1k.csv
  ```
- `grep "^A\|^ M"` filters for **A**dded or **M**odified files
- `cut -c 4-` cuts those first 3 characters and returns the filename starting from the 4th character

The other options are:

- `cp --parents` - creates directories along the way if they don't exist
- `rsync -R` because [`cp` doesn't support `--parents` on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246070/cp-parents-option-on-mac)

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p /c/temp/blah && cp $(git diff <your commit hash> --name-only) /c/temp/blah
```

I'm using Git Bash on windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have TortoiseGit, even before committing also you can export all the changed files to folder (which contains files under proper directory structure). Just perform following steps.

1. Right click on folder which you want to see changes
2. Select Commit to
3. Once files are visible in box, select all files
4. Right click - > Export selection to...
5. Select folder where you want to put these files.
6. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same requirement.
Got the input from the first answer and created a tool (Windows Only) for myself.
Which copies all the added/ modified files to a backup folder.

[image: Tool Overview]

[Git-Uncommited-Files-Backup-Tool-Windows](https://github.com/iamshz97/Git-Uncommited-Files-Backup-Tool-Windows)

Just wrote this quick for fun. Just posted incase it'd help someone. (Highly welcomed for modifications).

Also, you can schedule backups using the Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Gathered from different solutions, here's what I used:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD `git diff --name-only [from-commit-hash]` > changes.zip
```

It'll zip changes from any particular commit.

like:

```
git archive --format=zip HEAD `git diff --name-only 4a944407aec42222761cdc23c3e0b89a0c1e26a1` > changes.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script which can make this process a lot easier, it will copy all changed file to used defined directory and also maintain the directory structure of code base.

run:
sh scr.sh

================================================

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=`git ls-files --modified`
for x in $FILES
do
        prev_dir=$PWD
        echo "MY Dir = $prev_dir"
        mkdir -p $1/$x
        cd $1/$x
        cd ../
        rm -r *
        cp $prev_dir/$x ./.
        cd $prev_dir
done
```

================================================

Comment: how do I check FILES is empty and show message to terminal screen and set destination folder?

Comment: I change file in root folder and run your command, it'll create a folder with same name. Why it doesnt copy file to another folder instead create folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can export your last modified files via git ls-files --modified
Just create a .sh file with the following code And execute it.

```
#!/bin/sh
FILES=`git ls-files --modified`
export_dir="place your export dir"
for x in $FILES
do
   prev_dir=$PWD
   folder=$(dirname $x)
   echo "Exporting to..." $export_dir/$x
   cp $prev_dir/$x $export_dir/$x
done
```