# Git: how to exclude a subfolder in a repository?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have created a repository in a folder with my project, you know, `git init`, I have the Webstorm folder `.idea` and another one not related to this, I am not interested in keeping in the repository, and I don't want this folder to appear even as new files to add. 
I want to forget about these subfolders.

1. How can I exclude this subfolder before committing the whole repository?
2. How can I exclude this subfolder after committing the whole repository?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open the `.git/info/exclude` file in a text editor and add the folder to ignore. This file remains private to you. You can also create a `.gitignore` file in the repository's root directory, outside the `.git` directory and write the folder entry there. Then add this file to the repository to share with others what content should be ignored, should others have this directory-to-ignore in their repository too.

If you already committed this directory then just remove it with `git rm -r --cached`, commit the deletion and mark the directory ignored as I described above. You might want to make a backup of the directory before you wipe it.

Comment: I would recommend `git rm -r --cached` instead of `git rm -r` -- otherwise the directory will also be deleted from your working tree.

Comment: @Sven Marnach - hehe, that's a good comment, I deleted the folder without wanting, but I didn't need it this time!!!

Comment: @Mr Question: If you would still need it, you can of course get it back.  That's what a version control system is for after all.

Comment: I've added the line /css/ to the exclude folder, but I still have a list of deleted files from within that in my working tree. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: If you're trying to ignore files in a directory named css then say `css/`