# cp --parents option on mac

Tags: macos, command-line, command-line-arguments

On Linux, I have a --parents option available for the cp command so I can do

```
cp --parents test/withintest/go.rb test2
```

http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html

On Mac, I do not have this option available. Is there a way to do this on Mac? Why is this option not available?

PS. The purpose of --parents is the following:

> ‘--parents’ Form the name of each destination file by appending to the
>   target directory a slash and the specified name of the source file.
>
> The last argument given to cp must be the name of an existing
>   directory.
>
> For example, the command:
>
> ```
>       cp --parents a/b/c existing_dir
> ```
>
> copies the file a/b/c to existing_dir/a/b/c, creating any missing intermediate directories.

Comment: Just install it :) As with many GNU utilities, you can install them from a package manager, e.g. `brew install coreutils`.

Comment: For reference, after install coreutils above, you can then run `gcp --parents a/b/c existing_dir` since coreutils prepends a `g` to GNU commands that MacOS has its own version of.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `ditto` command on Mac OS X:

The basic form

```
ditto <src-path> <dst-path>
```

does what you want. There's a lot more options too - check out the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html).

Comment: Perfect.  `ditto some/dir/structure/file /tmp/some/dir/structure/file` creates the directories some/dir/structure under /tmp, as desired.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the original question. `cp --parents a/b/c existing_dir` and `ditto a/b/c existing_dir` seem to do different things.

Comment: @alecb I think the answer was addressing what the OP actually wanted to achieve, rather than the exact method. I was going through the same thought process when I discovered the `ditto` command.

Comment: Original question is to copy a *file* while preserving it's path hierarchy.  ditto copies over a whole dir tree - not a single file -- therefore, wrong answer.

Comment: That's wrong to use `ditto` when there is cross-platform `rsync` available. The "ditto" answer can't be designated as a correct answer. Sorry for being this nasty.

Comment: @KostaZ  misfire. The title says `mac` so this answer is viable.

Answer (score 102):

This bothered me quite a lot as well.
A workaround for this could be to use rsync.

```
rsync -R test/withintest/go.rb test2
```

has the same effect as `cp --parents` and OS X comes standard with rsync.

Comment: do you know why this might be failing with `find` and `xargs`? I tried `find . -name "foo" | xargs rsync -R '{}' destination/`

Comment: Downside of rsync is that is not installed by default on many distributions, is something you want to avoid using usually.

Answer (score 8):

You can install the GNU version of `cp` using [MacPorts](https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.html).

After MacPorts is installed you can install the coreutils packages:

```
sudo port install coreutils
```

Then you will be able to use the GNU version `cp` and other core utilitites (`ls`, `date`, `cat`, etc.) by prefixing the command with a `g`:

```
gcp --parents test/withintest/go.rb test2
```

If you want these GNU versions to be used by default you can add the GNU bin update your path. Add the following to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 4):

The Homebrew way:

Install `coreutils`

```sh
brew install coreutils
```

Use the `GNU` g- prefixed command

```
gcp --parents test/withintest/go.rb test2
```

Answer (score 4):

I used rsync and what I did was:

`rsync -R dir/**/file.json destination`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
mkdir -p `dirname "$file_path"` && cp "$old_dir/$file_path" "$file_path"
```

This first creates the directory with all intermediates in the relative file path. Then, it copies the file to the newly created directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would not replace mac cp with GNU cp. I would also not used ditto because it is not cross-platform. Instead use cross-platform tools, such as rsync:

```
rsync <srcDir/srcFile> <dst>
```

Result: dst/srcDir/srcFile

Comment: this one didn't quite work for me, `rsync old/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/xcb/xcb_qpa_lib.pro new` gives me `new/xcb_qpa_lib.pro` on a mac

Comment: See stephan's answer below, similar but it works on mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the -dir option to rsync to get it to work for me:

```
rsync -R -dir a/b tmp
```

The results:

```
$ find a
a
a/b
a/b/f1.txt
a/c
a/c/f2.txt
a/d
a/d/f3.txt

$ find tmp
tmp
tmp/a
tmp/a/b
tmp/a/b/f1.txt
```